# how to edit a js object/function

Tags: javascript

Hi i am using an api but i should make a patch for it

```
Songapi.prototype.goPlaySong=Songapi.prototype.goPlaySong.toString().replace('["universal","emi","warner"]) !== -1','false');
```

doesn't work
also tried

```
Songapi.prototype.goPlaySong=Function(Songapi.prototype.goPlaySong.toString().replace('["universal","emi","warner"]) !== -1','false'));
```

or

```
Songapi.prototype.goPlaySong=eval(Songapi.prototype.goPlaySong.toString().replace('["universal","emi","warner"]) !== -1','false'));
```

still couldn't do it any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure you can edit functions just like that. You could maybe store their code into a string, replace, and then eval the string, and finally set it as the function.

Comment: He wants to replace a test in a parsed function by an hard coded false boolean.

Comment: @Virus721: Oh!  Thanks.  I didn't see how that was working.

Comment: It seems to me you don't even understand what you are doing. You cannot just replace something there

Answer (score 3):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/ARmLw/)

`SongApi` is a `constructor` a.k.a a class.

```
function inherits(child, parent) {
  function temp() {};
  temp.prototype = parent.prototype;
  child.prototype = new temp();
  child.prototype.constructor = child;
};

var CustomizedApi = function() {
    SongApi.call(this);
};
inherits(CustomizedApi, Songapi);
// or use Object.create for inheritance.
CustomizedApi.prototype = Object.create(SongApi.prototype);

/**
 * @override
 */
CustomizedApi.prototype.goPlaySong = function() {
   // override with whatever you want.
};
var api = new CustomizedApi;
api.goPlaySong();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
eval('var code = ' + Songapi.prototype.goPlaySong.toString().replace('["universal","emi","warner"]) !== -1','false'));

Songapi.prototype.goPlaySong = code;
```

But this is absolute dirtiness.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newgoPlaySong=Songapi.prototype.goPlaySong.toString().replace('$.inArray(response.provider,["universal","emi","warner"]) !== -1','false');
eval('Songapi.prototype.goPlaySong = '+gecicigoPlaySong+';');
```

it worked thanks